# Angular.js - change content once both inputs have been entered?

Tags: css, angularjs, variables, updates

I'm pretty new to angular (as you might guess). I'm trying to understand the best way to change content depending on what gets input in  fields.

For example, I have

```
<div ng-app = "">

    <p>Enter variable 1: <input type = "number" ng-model = "var1"></p>

    <p>Enter variable 2: <input type ="number" ng-model ="var2"></p>
```

And I'm trying to display the product of the two variables, once both have been entered:

```
    <p>Your total value is
    {{ (var1 * var2).isFinite? (var1 * var2) :  'Please enter a number' }} </p>
```

However, this doesn't work - it always displays 'Please enter a number'.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: isFinite() should be called with parenthesis, since it it's function.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep that logic out of the HTML and in your controller if possible and add another function to set a new value in your view (either num1 * num2 or "Please enter a number").

```
$scope.isFinite = function(num1, num2) {
    //Your logic for this function
}

$scope.checkFinite() {
     $scope.answer = null;

     if($scope.isFinite($scope.num1, $scope.num2)) {
         $scope.answer = $scope.num1 * $scope.num2;
     };
     else {
         $scope.answer = "Please enter a number"
     };
}
```

Then update your html as so:
`<p>Your total value is {{answer}} </p>`

You will need to run $scope.checkFinite() when your input changes, there are a couple of ways you can do that:

```
<div ng-app = "">

<p>Enter variable 1: <input type = "number" ng-change="checkFinite()" ng-model = "var1"></p>

<p>Enter variable 2: <input type ="number" ng-change="checkFinite()" ng-model ="var2"></p>
```

Basically, if the values change in the inputs, it will run $scope.checkFinite(), its a nifty little directive in Angular.

Another way you can do this, where you run the function ($scope.checkFinite()) when either inputs change is through a couple of watches in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('num1', function() {
     $scope.checkFinite();
});

$scope.$watch('num2', function() {
     $scope.checkFinite();
});
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

PS Don't go crazy with $scope.$watch, it's easy to fall into that trap.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to use ng-if:

```
<p>Enter variable 1: <input type = "number" ng-model = "var1"></p>

<p>Enter variable 2: <input type ="number" ng-model ="var2"></p>

<p>
  <div ng-if="var1 && var2">Your total value is {{(var1 * var2)}}</div>
  <div ng-if="!var1 || !var2">'Please enter a number'</div>
</p>
```